# ASP.NET MVC, outputting source code in error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I've wound up in a very odd place. Due to circumstances beyond my control, a machine burned up before I was able to commit certain changes to a backup/repository. This is only one file that didn't get backed up, but it was an important one to me nonetheless.

However the binary that was generated still lives on an internal test webpage. So my first thought was to try a decompiler, which has given some results, but it isn't very accurate.

I noticed that when I do not have much configured for ASP.NET MVC, errors show the source code of the file that threw an exception if there is no kind of handling.

I was wondering if I might be able to use this to get my code back, but the output length seems limited to 9 lines.

So.

(A) is this possible?

(B) is there any way to get more than 9 lines?

(C) are there any good tools for this kind of thing?

I am not trying to hack. I own the site, and the code. It is just an unfortunate situation.

Comment: Did you try Reflector?  It is quite good at getting useful source code.

Comment: Another one to look at is IL Spy

Comment: try .Net Reflector http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/95789cdb-08f9-4dae-9b2f-fc45a452ad77

Comment: @EricJ. even better with the new debug-into stuff in the VS plugin :)

Comment: @Eric J - same reflector as posted, or are there more than one?

Comment: there are heaps, telerik has one, Redgate has one, i havent used any of the others but there are a lot. Reflector is redgates

Comment: @Ciel: I have used RedGate's.  I think they have a 30 day free trial (last I checked anyhow).

Comment: Yes, I am trying the redgate one out now. I was using the Telerik one and it was pretty bad results.

Comment: There is also [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about PDB files. There's a question about it: [Obtaining information about executable code from exe/pdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970443/obtaining-information-about-executable-code-from-exe-pdb)

You can inspect with http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37456/How-To-Inspect-the-Content-of-a-Program-Database-P but it only shows little information.

And as you can read in http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx

> *The actual file format of a PDB file is a closely guarded secret but Microsoft provides APIs to return the data for debuggers.*